# Unexpected row(s) of NAs when selecting subset of dataframe

Tags: r

When selecting a subset of data from a dataframe, I get row(s) entirely made up of NA values that were not present in the original dataframe. For example:

```
example.df[example.df$census_tract == 27702, ]
```

returns:

```
      census_tract number_households_est
NA              NA                    NA
23611        27702                  2864
```

Where did that first row of NAs come from? And why is it returned even though `example.df$census_tract != 27702` for that row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because there is a missing observation

```
> sum(is.na(example.df$census_tract))
[1] 1
> example.df[which(is.na(example.df$census_tract)), ]
   census_tract number_households_est
64           NA                    NA
```

When `==` evaluates the 64th row it gives `NA` because by default we can't know wheter 27702 is equal to the missing value. Therefore the result is missing (aka `NA`). So a `NA` is putted in the logical vector used for indexing purposes. And this gives, by default, a full-of-`NA` row, because we are asking for a row but "we don't know which one".

The proper way is

```
> example.df[example.df$census_tract %in% 27702, ]
      census_tract number_households_est
23611        27702                  2864
```

HTH, Luca

Comment: This is also a case where `which` can help: `example.df[which(example.df$census_tract == 27702), ]`

Comment: Thanks. Why does `==` match the NA row? And why does it report a row number of NA when your version reports 64?